# FactoryBean and custom-scoped bean

Tags: spring, scope

I'm using a custom FactoryBean to build up a set of singleton objects. From the FactoryBean I programmatically call the 'autowireBeanProperties' to inject the dependencies into the beans.

```
context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(o, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME, false);
```

(I know this is not an optimal scenario, but I had the reason to design things this way, and I'm planning to change, but it takes more time then I thought)

One of the dependencies is a custom-scoped bean let's call it 'userSession' scope.

I get the following error:

```
Property 'scopedBean' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.connector': Scope 'userSession' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown identity: null
```

I tried with both  and a custom ScopedProxy (which instantiates the inner userSession-scoped object only upon method calls), but the result is the same.
The stack seems like this:

```
UserSessionScope.get(String, ObjectFactory) line: 23    
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).doGetBean(String, Class<T>, Object[], boolean) line: 329    
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactory).getBean(String) line: 194   
SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget() line: 33 
JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(Object, Method, Object[]) line: 184   
$Proxy0.setScopedBean(IScopedBean) line: not available  
MySingletonBean.setScopedBean(IScopedBean) line: 51
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 39  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 25  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 597  
BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl$PropertyTokenHolder, PropertyValue) line: 1134 
BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(PropertyValue) line: 904   
BeanWrapperImpl(AbstractPropertyAccessor).setPropertyValues(PropertyValues, boolean, boolean) line: 75  
BeanWrapperImpl(AbstractPropertyAccessor).setPropertyValues(PropertyValues) line: 57    
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).applyPropertyValues(String, BeanDefinition, BeanWrapper, PropertyValues) line: 1424  
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).populateBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, BeanWrapper) line: 1132 
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).autowireBeanProperties(Object, int, boolean) line: 379   
MyFactoryBean.processInjection(Object) line: 68
```

I cannot imagine why the invoke has been called in the instantiation phase...
I have no logic to do that...

Another thing is: I have no bean named 'scopedTarget.connector'.

Thanks for any clues

(BTW: I'm using Spring 3.2 release)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was my fault. i was wondering why I'm getting that irrelevant stacktrace...

The problem was elsewhere...